# ReactJs, TypeScript, MobX - Unable to get MobX refreshing screen on store data update

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I am having an issue with mobx. In fact, I have a simple chat room which uses a WebSocketService defined by myself. While this service abstract the exchanges with my API, the chat itself handle the store of the messages.

**main.tsx (entry point)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {App} from './app';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';
import {createStores} from "app/stores";
import {Provider} from "mobx-react";
import {LoggedUserModel} from "app/models";
import {newUUID} from "app/utils/UUID";

// prepare MobX stores
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const rootStore = createStores(history, new LoggedUserModel(newUUID(), 'User'));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider {...rootStore}>
        <App history={history}/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**index.tsx (App)**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router';

import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';

import { Chat } from "app/containers/Chat";

// render react DOM
export const App = hot(({history}) => {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Chat}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
});
```

**Chat.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import style from './style.css'

import {RouteComponentProps} from 'react-router';
import ChatChannelMessagesList from "app/components/Chat/ChatChannelMessagesListComponent";
import ChatChannelInput from "app/components/Chat/ChatChannelInputComponent";
import {inject, observer} from "mobx-react";
import {STORE_LOGGED_USER, STORE_MESSAGES} from "app/constants";
import {LoggedUserStore, MessagesStore} from "app/stores";
import {newUUID} from "app/utils/UUID";
import {MessageModel} from "app/models";
import WebSocketService from "app/services/webSocketService";

export interface ChatProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
    [STORE_LOGGED_USER]: LoggedUserStore;
    [STORE_MESSAGES]: MessagesStore;
}

export interface ChatState {
    WebSocketService: WebSocketService
}

@inject(STORE_LOGGED_USER, STORE_MESSAGES)
@observer
export class Chat extends React.Component<ChatProps, ChatState> {
    constructor(props: ChatProps, context: any) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            WebSocketService: new WebSocketService(event => {
                // add the new message to state
                this.onMessage(event)
            })
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.WebSocketService.connect(this.props[STORE_LOGGED_USER].getLoggedUser.id)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.state.WebSocketService.disconnect(this.props[STORE_LOGGED_USER].getLoggedUser.id)
    }

    addMessageToScreen(message: string) {
        // add the new message to state
        this.props[STORE_MESSAGES].addMessage(new MessageModel(newUUID(), message));

        console.log(this.getMessages())
    }

    onMessage(event) {
        console.log(event.data);
        this.addMessageToScreen(event.data)
    }

    sendMessage(input: string) {
        this.addMessageToScreen(input);
        this.state.WebSocketService.message(this.props[STORE_LOGGED_USER].getLoggedUser.id, input)
    }

    getMessages() {
        return this.props[STORE_MESSAGES].getMessages
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id={"chat"} className={style.container}>
                <div className="rox">
                    <div className="row-offset-11 row-11 row-sm-11 row-md-11 row-lg-11 row-xl-11">
                        <ChatChannelMessagesList messages={this.getMessages()}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row-1 row-sm-1 row-md-1 row-lg-1 row-xl-1">
                        <ChatChannelInput onSendClicked={(input: string) => this.sendMessage(input)}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Chat
```

I have no errors, everything runs smoothly but updates doesn'tt refresh the screen and I don't get why..

**messageStore**

```
import { observable, computed, action } from 'mobx';
import { MessageModel } from 'app/models';

export class MessagesStore {
  constructor(items: Array<MessageModel>) {
    this.Messages = items;
  }

  @observable public Messages: Array<MessageModel>;

  @computed
  get getMessages() {
    return this.Messages;
  }

  @action
  addMessage = (item: MessageModel): void => {
    this.Messages.push(item);
  };

  @action
  setMessages = (items: Array<MessageModel>): void => {
    this.Messages = items
  };

  @action
  deleteMessage = (id: string): void => {
    this.Messages = this.Messages.filter((Message) => Message.id !== id);
  };

}

export default MessagesStore;
```

I think I've put everything, feel free to ask more details and thanks for any help !

> **Disclaimer: First time using MobX**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems:

In your `MessagesStore`, you're not using **@observable** correctly.
**@observable** makes the initial value of your field observable. But you're immediately replacing this value with a regular, non-observable array in `MessageStore`'s constructor. So `MessageStore.Messages` will never be observable, and won't trigger any re-render of your observer components.

What you should do is initializing the `MessageStore.Messages` field with an array, which will be observable, and never assign a non-observable array to this field.
If you need to replace this array with another one, as you're doing in `MessageStore`'s constructor and `MessageStore.deleteMessage`, you should use MobX's observable arrays' `.replace` method, which will replace the contents of the observable array with another array's contents.

```
export class MessagesStore {
  constructor(items: Array<MessageModel>) {
    this.Messages.replace(items);
  }

  @observable public Messages = new Array<MessageModel>();

  ...

  @action
  deleteMessage = (id: string): void => {
    this.Messages.replace(this.Messages.filter((Message) => Message.id !== id));
  };
}
```

That way, `MessageStore.Messages` will be observable, and your components observing its changes will re-render as expected.

The second issue is that your `Chat` component is not observing `MessageStore.Messages`'s changes, so said changes will never trigger re-renders for `Chat`. The reason is the following (from [MobX's documentation](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html)):

> MobX can do a lot, but it cannot make primitive values observable (although it can wrap them in an object see boxed observables). So not the values that are observable, but the properties of an object. This means that @observer actually reacts to the fact that you dereference a value.

```
  <ChatChannelMessagesList messages={this.getMessages()}/>
```

Here, you're only passing `MessageStore.Messages` as a value to `ChatChannelMessagesList`. You're not dereferencing it (which means accessing any of its properties, for example iterating the array), so `Chat`, even though marked as @observer, won't react to `MessageStore.Messages`'s contents changes.

The component that will react to these changes is the first that will actually access the array's contents, which would probably be `ChatChannelMessagesList`. My guess is that this component is not marked as @observer, and never reacts to messages updates, and that's the reason why you're not seeing any re-renders.

You have two solutions to this problem:
 - dereference (access the contents of) `MessageStore.Messages` inside `Chat`, so it re-renders when there are new messages
 - make `ChatChannelMessagesList` (or the first component dereferencing `MessageStore.Messages`) @observer, so it reacts to the changes.

The second solution is better, because you should always dereference your observables as late as possible, to avoid useless re-renders of parent components which are not dependent on these changes. In your case, re-rendering `Chat` when the contents of `MessageStore.Messages` change would be useless, because `Chat` would render the same thing anyway.

**In summary:**

- Don't reassign fields containing observable arrays with new arrays, change the contents of your observable array instead.
- @observer components re-render when you access the **properties** of your observables, not their values. The @observer components should be those accessing these properties.

Comment: Thanks Alex this detailed answer :) really helped !!